# Given a JSON API response, how to build a JSON object for React?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

My API will be returning results like so:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":2,
      "title":"Something",
   },
   {  
      "id":231,
      "title":"Another",
   },
   ...
]
```

Then in my React app, I need to build a JSON object like so:

```
const fields = [
  {
    name: 'Something',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      {},
      { label: '1', value: '1' },
      { label: '2', value: '2' },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'Another',
    type: 'select',
    options: [
      {},
      { label: '1', value: '1' },
      { label: '2', value: '2' },
    ],
  },
  ...
]
```

the options will remain constant (not dependent on what the server returns).

How can I build this JSON object dynamically based on the API results

### Update

```
var origArray = [ {id:1, title: "xxx"},
                  {id:2, title: "eee"},
                  {id:3, title: "rrr"},
                  {id:4, title: "ffff"}];

const fieldoptions = {
  type: 'select',
  options: [
    {},
    { label: '1', value: '1' },
    { label: '2', value: '2' },
  ]
};

const fields = origArray.map(item => ({
 name: item.title,
 fieldoptions
}));

console.log('fields');
console.log(fields)
```

Problem is there is a parent of `fieldoptions` which should not exist in the output.

(4) [Object, Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
fieldoptions
:
Object
name
:
"execution"

Comment: `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: What have you tried? You could probably just iterate across with even just a for loop and then make fields[idx].name = result[idx].title. This seems pretty trivial, is there more context you can provide?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest thank you! would you mind answering w an example so I can accept? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to call .map() on your array, which takes a function and applies it to all the elements in the array.

This function will be what transforms the data you have, into what you want by adding the fields etc.

```
const fields = {
  type: 'select',
  options: [
    {},
    { label: '1', value: '1' },
    { label: '2', value: '2' },
  ]
};

const result = data.map(item => ({
 name: item.title,
 ...fields
}));
```

Comment: Thanks but that seems to be building the object incorrectly. It is results in 0: fields, name, where fields shouldn't exists and all the items currently in fields should be moved up a level. Does that make sense?

Comment: `fields` as a parent shouldn't exist

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest just updated the Q with the latest code snippet... Did I implement your suggestion wrong?

Comment: That did it... Thanks!